# Where can a list of popular recording artists and their songs be downloaded

Tags: music

I'm trying to find a list of popular recording artists and their songs (not the actual music, but their names and titles).  The list could be a simple **ascii file**, or **csv** or **spreadsheet**, or even an **sqlite** file, anything that I can download as a single file and isn't a proprietary format that requires costly software. Also, I'm familiar with Billboards website, RIAA's Gold and Platinum list and Wikipedia's various lists.  I've also found enormous databases that are hundreds of gigabytes in size and talk of a million songs, but I haven't figured out how to use it.  The entire Bible is 4.13MB in byte size, so I figure if the file is over a gigabyte then it has a lot of extraneous data, perhaps audio or video or some other data.  I'm interested in **text** data, not audio or video.

My ultimate goal is simple.  I'm trying to find an early 70s song from youth that I heard over and over.  It had a fast lively energetic beat at it's climax, and definitely wasn't a slow ballad.  But I haven't heard it again since.  It was probably in about 1974 but could have been recorded earlier than that.  It was popular on AM contemporary listening radio, but I haven't heard it a single time since the 70s.  I'd like to find it again.

So, I want to collect a list of songs, weed through them one by one, and eventually find it.  Neil Diamond, Tony Orlando, BJ Thomas were artists that I thought it might have been, but so far I haven't discovered it.

Here are some examples of song data I've already discovered:
WIKIPEDIA -- they have a plethora of lists. However, they are usually by year and genre --

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Billboard_number-one_adult_contemporary_hits
(this is a directory to links specific to each there. there are a plethora of similar lists for other genres on WIKIPEDIA)

I need a portable file, but here's is a link to a 300GB "million song dataset" billed to run on an AWS cloud server:
http://millionsongdataset.com/pages/getting-dataset/

Comment: okay, I'm going to provide my links in an edit to my question above.

Comment: Any idea on why this dataset is not available anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Kaggle dataset contains csv files of around 600k audio tracks with associated artists' names:

https://www.kaggle.com/yamaerenay/spotify-dataset-19212020-160k-tracks